# SQL Query not working with certain times in where condition

Tags: sql, time, db2, toad

I have a table created in DB2. This table has 4 fields ID(Integer), Shift(Integer), Start_time(Time) and End_time(Time). Data in this table looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLoui.png). When I run the this `select * from shifttimes where '6:29:59' between start_time and End_time` SQL query, it returns "1" as shift number. Any time between 5AM to 1:29PM, it returns "1" as shift number, this is good.

When I run the this `select * from shifttimes where '20:29:59' between start_time and End_time` sql query, it returns "2" as shift number. Any time between 1:30PM to 8:29:59PM, it returns "2" as shift number, this also good.

Problem is when I run this `select * from shifttimes where '20:30:00' between start_time and End_time` sql query, it returns nothing. 
Any time from 20:30:00 to 4:59:00, query returns nothing. 
I'm executing all these queries in TOAD for DB2.

Comment: Have you tried to convert the string into a TIME value? Like this: TIME ('12:00:00')

Comment: I interpret this as shift 3 spans two days across midnight but how is DB2 supposed to know that?  If that's the case, you need datetime instead.

Comment: Yep you need a timestamp to do these betweens that cross midnight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic that you want is:

```
select *
from shifttimes
where (start_time < end_time and '20:29:59' between start_time and End_time) or
      (start_time > end_time and '20:29:59 not between end_time and start_time)
```

The problem (as you have probably noticed) are shifts that go over the midnight boundary.  The second condition handles that.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, Gordon. After posting this question i figured out that the query is not working as end time is less than start time.